# How to automount an SMB share and keep it mounted and remount automatically if disconnected temporarily?

Tags: network, mount, sharing, smb, automount

Been using a gem of an app called [AutoMounter](https://automounter.app/), but it seems to have perhaps been having some issues in Big Sur occasionally.

How can one automatically mount SMB shares in macOS 11 (Big Sur) with just in-built functionality while also making sure the shares are remounted if any disconnections occur temporarily (or you take a system away from the office for a few hours and then come back)?

Comment: Is there an update to make sure it is compatible to Big Sur?

Comment: Do you have the helper app installed https://automounter.app/helper/?

Comment: @Gilby yes, helper is installed. The biggest problem was a panic that was somehow associated with AutoMounter. This is the big red flag that made me think that I should consider a more standard alternative to see if I can remove it from the equation.